# Can't install less-loader in VueCLI3 project

Tags: vue-cli-3, less-loader

Some pages of my project use less to render,so I run the npm command to install less and less-loader but find just less can successfully installed,for unknown reason, the less-loader keep falied to install and throw error like this:

```
PS E:\myprogramming\tutorial\frontEND\eduResourceCode\Vue教程\复习\Vue脚手架CLI3\vuexdemo_> npm i less-loader
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: webpack@4.46.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from @intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin@1.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin
npm ERR!     @intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin@"^1.0.5" from @vue/cli-service@4.5.13
npm ERR!     node_modules/@vue/cli-service
npm ERR!       peer @vue/cli-service@"^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0-0" from @vue/cli-plugin-babel@4.5.13
npm ERR!       node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel
npm ERR!         dev @vue/cli-plugin-babel@"~4.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       4 more (@vue/cli-plugin-eslint, @vue/cli-plugin-router, ...)
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from @soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@1.8.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     @soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@"^1.7.1" from @vue/cli-service@4.5.13
npm ERR!     node_modules/@vue/cli-service
npm ERR!       peer @vue/cli-service@"^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0-0" from @vue/cli-plugin-babel@4.5.13
npm ERR!       node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel
npm ERR!         dev @vue/cli-plugin-babel@"~4.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       4 more (@vue/cli-plugin-eslint, @vue/cli-plugin-router, ...)
npm ERR!   18 more (@vue/cli-plugin-babel, @vue/cli-plugin-eslint, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! less-loader@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@5.38.1
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"^5.0.0" from less-loader@9.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/less-loader
npm ERR!     less-loader@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\hw\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hw\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-13T12_28_33_753Z-debug.log
```

But my dev server can't run without less-loader, I try many methods, like reinstalling two dependencies,use vue-cil to download the plugin with same name, or stick other less-loader tag to my `package.json` but all don't work.

I find a possible,but weird reason is my node_modules don't have a less-loader folder! Now how I can fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I merge my project by take the css-prodecessor,and it solve my problem.but I still confuse.
I don't like solve problem by merge because it will break some files what I already finished.
If I can have less-loader after my project built that will be better.